# What is meant by SKU1 and SKU2 in Router frequency support?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet

What is meant by SKU 1 and SKU 2 for Router frequency support?

This is a D-link 4G/LTE Mobile Router. Model - DWR-932C

The data sheet can be accessed from [DWR-932C Data Sheet](https://dlinkmea.com/upload/downloadable/DWR_932C_E1_Datasheet_01_WW__2__5c36fc9c78cd7.pdf)

[SKU 1 & SKU 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUoMU.png)

Answer (score 0):

#### What is meant by SKU 1 and SKU 2 for Router frequency support?

It is explained in the data sheet you linked:

> Supported frequency band is dependent upon regional hardware version.

[image]

[image]

Source: [DWR_932C_E1_Datasheet_01_WW__2__5c36fc9c78cd7.pdf](https://dlinkmea.com/upload/downloadable/DWR_932C_E1_Datasheet_01_WW__2__5c36fc9c78cd7.pdf)